# Javascript reads only first elements(from array) in nested for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, statements

I have the following issue. There's a problem I have to solve.

> Fruit or Vegetable    Write a JS function to print "fruit" , "vegetable"
>   or "unknown" depending on the input string.
>
> - Fruits are: banana, apple, kiwi, cherry, lemon, grapes, peach
> - Vegetable are: tomato, cucumber, pepper, onion, garlic, parsley
> - All others are unknown
>
>   The input comes as array of one string element, the name of the
>     fruit.    The output should be printed to the console.
>
> Example: input ['banana'] output: fruit 
>   Example: input ['cucumber'] output: vegetable 
>  
>   Example: input ['pizza']  output: unknown

and I've tried something like that.

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < vegetables.length; k++) {
        if (inputArr[i] === fruits[j]) {
          return ' fruit ';
        } else if (inputArr[i] === vegetables[k]) {
          return 'vegetable';
        } else {
          return 'unknown';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['tomato'])); //Returns vegetable
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['banana'])); //Returns fruit
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['cucumber'])); //Returns unknown
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['pizza'])); // Returns unknown
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['appple'])); //Returns unknown
```

Don't know why , but it works only for the 0 index of the array , for example , for 'tomato' it returns vegetable , but if I try it for the other vegetables , it returns unknown. If I remove that last statement

```
else{
 return false;
}
```

Then , cucumber becomes vegetable , but apple gots undefined? I'm a bit confused , so I'll be glad if someone explain me why this happens. Thank you.

Comment: Your discovery - the fact that if you remove the return "unknown"; line, a bunch of these cases work - basically points to the bug here. Try running through your code on the cucumber example and literally go line-by-line like the Javascript interpreter would

Comment: you have to return unknown when the list exhausts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: check the values in the first iteration, `i=0, j=0, k=0` then you have both `if` and `else if` returning false so the `else` block is getting executed with returns `unknown`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a massive nested unnecessary `for loop` there. The task is pretty straightforward

> The input comes as array of one string element, the name of the **fruit**.
>   The output should be printed to the console.

You just have to grab that first `inputArr` value, which is a *string* and check if its value actually in your `fruits`, `vegetables` or else `unknown`.

Something like,

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
    var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
    var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

    var val = inputArr[0];

    return fruits.indexOf(val) !== -1 ? 'fruit' : vegetables.indexOf(val) !== -1 ? 'vegetables' : 'unknown';
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Let's break the code above,

```
// This is to grab the string from the first value in `inputArr` and store in `val`.
var val = inputArr[0];
```

And returning,

> <sup>1</sup> `fruits.indexOf(val) !== -1 ? 'fruit'` :
>
> <sup>2</sup> `vegetables.indexOf(val) !== -1 ? 'vegetables' :`
>
> <sup>3</sup> `'unknown';`

1. Check whether `val` exists in `fruits`, if it does, return 'fruit' or else run <sup>2</sup>
2. Check whether `val` exists in `vegetables`, if it does, return 'vegetables' or else run <sup>3</sup>
3. Return 'undefined'

This operation equals to,

```
if (fruits.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
    return 'fruit';
}
else if (vegetables.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
    return 'vegetables';
}
else {
    return 'unknown';
}
```

**More info:**

**`?:`** is a conditional (ternary) operator. [(Read more here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's pretty handy to evaluate expression

*e.g.*

```
var myval = 1;
console.log(myval ? 'true' : 'false'); // true

myval = false;
console.log(myval ? 'true' : 'false'); // false
```

**`indexOf`** is an array native function, which you can check the index of a value in an array. ([Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf))

*e.g.*

```
var myarr = ['test', 'tost', 'aww'];
console.log(myarr.indexOf('tost')); // returns 1
console.log(myarr.indexOf('tosts')); // returns -1 (value not found)
```

Comment: Thank you mate , such a helpful answer , but the problem is that I am not that advanced in javascript yet. So I don't know how this last line of return with ' ? ' and ' : ' works :( It works but I can't understand it.

Comment: good explanation. Thank you very much. Fixed your answer as marked.

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestions:**

1. Check if the current item is a fruit and only if you made sure that it is not a fruit, check if it is a vegetable.
2. Return `unknown` only after confirming if the current item is neither a fruit nor a vegetable.

---

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {

    var isFruit = false;
    var isVegetable = false;

    for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
      if (inputArr[i] === fruits[j]) {
        result.push('fruit');
        isFruit = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isFruit) {
      // skip rest of the body of the loop as it is a Fruit
      continue;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < vegetables.length; j++) {
      if (inputArr[i] === vegetables[j]) {
        result.push('vegetable');
        isVegetable = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isVegetable === false) {
      // at this point we know its neither a fruit nor a vegetable
      result.push('unknown');
    }

  }
  return result;
}

console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['tomato', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'pizza', 'apple']));
// [ 'vegetable', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'unknown', 'fruit' ]
```

---

**Improvements with `Array#indexOf`**

JavaScript Arrays come with a lot of built-in methods which will help is with basic sorting and searching. You can use the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of an element in an array. It will return `-1` if it is not found. If we rewrite with that information,

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i += 1) {
    if (fruits.indexOf(inputArr[i]) !== -1) {
      result.push('fruit');
    } else if (vegetables.indexOf(inputArr[i]) !== -1) {
      result.push('vegetable');
    } else {
      result.push('unknown');
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['tomato', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'pizza', 'apple']));
// [ 'vegetable', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'unknown', 'fruit' ]
```

---

**Improvements with `Array#indexOf` and `Array#map`**

Now, you can write the same with functional programming approach. You can apply a function to each of the elements of `inputArr` with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

  return inputArr.map(function(currentItem) {
    if (fruits.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1) {
      return 'fruit';
    } else if (vegetables.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1) {
      return 'vegetable';
    }
    return 'unknown';
  });
}

console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['tomato', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'pizza', 'apple']));
// [ 'vegetable', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'unknown', 'fruit' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];
  
  if(inputArr === undefined || !inputArr.length) return 'unknown';

  if(fruits.indexOf(inputArr[0]) !== -1) return 'fruit';
  if(vegetables.indexOf(inputArr[0]) !== -1) return 'vegetable';
  return 'unknown';
}

console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['banana']));
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['tomato']));
console.log(fruitOrVegetable(['xxx']));
console.log(fruitOrVegetable([]));
console.log(fruitOrVegetable());
```

Comment: Please check now, Silly mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** You have misplaced `return "unknown"`. Consider this:

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
 var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
 var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < vegetables.length; k++) {
      if (inputArr[i] === fruits[j]) {
        return ' fruit ';
      } else if (inputArr[i] === vegetables[k]) {
        return 'vegetable';}
      }
    }
  }
return "unknown";
}
```

**Updated answer according to comments**

1. > Don't know why , but it works only for the 0 index of the array

Reason is you are returning value right inside of your loop. So it never       runs to the end. To fix that put `return "unknown";` outside of the loop.

2. In general you have messed with loops and code should be simplified. You can ask for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) whenever you think your code can be better, but you don't know how to do that.
3. It is good practice to simplify code to never get confused with it. For example you could write as below:

   ```
    function isVegetable(inputArr)
    {
       var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];        

      for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < vegetables.length; k++) {
           if (inputArr[i] === vegetables[k]) {
             return true;
           }
         }
       }
     return false;
     }


    function isFruit(inputArr)
    {
         var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];

       for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
       for (var k = 0; k < fruits.length; k++) {
           if (inputArr[i] === fruits[k]) {
               return true;
               }
           }
        }
       return false;
    }

    function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr)
    {
        if(isVegetable(inputArr)) return "vegetable";  
        if(isFruit(inputArr)) return "fruit";
        return "unknown";
    }
   ```

Comment: And here, I am still wondering why those loops still there, yet selected as an answer. I hope future readers wouldn't be misled by this approach.

Comment: I was thinking to provide better code for this question, but found that you( @choz ) has already done that

Comment: Since yours is selected one. You should try and edit your answer for better approach. It doesn't matter where you get the code from. At least its for OP and future readers' sake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `return vegetable` is the reason why it's only working for index 0. Because after first loop it returns a value and function ends. Instead initialize outputArray at start and set values to that array `outputArray[i] = 'veg'` and at the end `return outputArray`
 Next thing is don't nest too much loops within each other. Instead use check for veg or fruit separately inside large for loop:
 `for() {...}` `for() {...}` 
Sorry couldn't complete codes cause I'm writing from my phone

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way if it wil be preferable to you:-

```
function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) {
  var fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'cherry', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'peach'];
  var vegetables = ['tomato', 'cucumber', 'pepper', 'onion', 'garlic', 'parsley'];

  if ( fruits.indexOf( inputArr[0] ) > -1 ){
     return 'fruits';
  }else if ( vegetables.indexOf( inputArr[0] ) > -1 ){
     return 'vegetable';
  }else{
     return 'unknown';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your code like this, it will work file.**

function fruitOrVegetable(inputArr) 
{

```
    var fruits = ['banana' , 'apple' , 'kiwi' , 'cherry' , 'lemon' , 'grapes' , 'peach'];
    var vegetables = ['tomato' , 'cucumber' , 'pepper' , 'onion' , 'garlic' , 'parsley'];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < inputArr.length ; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0 ; j < fruits.length ; j++)
        {
            if(inputArr[i] === fruits[j]){
                    return ' fruit ';
                    }
        }
        for(var k = 0 ; k < vegetables.length ; k++)
        {

                 if(inputArr[i] === vegetables[k]){
                    return 'vegetable';
                }

        }

    }
                  return 'unknown';
}
```

Result:

fruitOrVegetable(['tomato']);
"vegetable"
fruitOrVegetable(['banana']);
" fruit "

fruitOrVegetable(['qwe']);
"unknown"